# Align label and input vertical

Tags: css, 960.gs

I want to present input forms in horizontal, want to have its labels as header (1st line is header include all labels of input form, 2nd line toward are repeated input forms).
I try to use 960 Grid System using `grid_2, grid_3` for example apply for each field and its label.

However, the input has border, but label doesn't, so the input fields was not aligned tightly with header (labels). If I try

```
input
{
border: 0;
}
```

then it aligns correctly. But using this way I can not see the input field visible.

How can I align it vertical without different 1 or 2 px of border of input?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the grid system is intended for use on labels and input fields.

Instead of applying `grid_X` class directly to label and field, you should apply to `<div>` that wraps around these input and labels, OR customize the grid class by defining `input.grid_x` and adjust the width.